# Is the PHP language resultantly C?

Tags: php, c, programming-languages

**Ok: I edited my question:** I heard somewhere that php language is written in C.

So what happens for example when you run a function in php such as `date("Ymd");` or `file_get_contents("file.txt");`?

Does it translate that code to C and request to server, or does php do it?

And if it does translate it and request, that means basically it is C?

Comment: PHP is written in C, not C++. Why don't you take a peek in the PHP source code and see for yourself?

Comment: no it does not translate anything into c++, although facebook developed a compiler that does translate PHP into C code, and then into machine language, called hiphop or someting like that.

Comment: The PHP interpreter was written in C. A `date()` call indeed gets executed by an internal compiled library that was written in C.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That is incorrect.

If you mean the language PHP is implemented in, it is C, not C++; see the [PHP wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), under Implementation Language.

That does not, however, mean that it "translates" code to C; PHP is an interpreted language.

While executing code, it does of course have to use functions written in C, since it is itself using C. However, no "translation" into C occurs; the code is simply parsed by the PHP language and the language then calls, itself, what is appropriate.

You might want to read [more on interpreted languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language), that should give you a better understanding.

Comment: I ask, why this? Where is the advantage? It is not more useful to directly code in C?

Comment: @Francesco The advantage is that you can develop easier and faster. That's what aim interpreted language. But yes, you can perfectly code your website in C ... if you have time ...

Answer (score 1):

In any interpreted language the language syntax is just a wrapper for functions and constructs implemented in the language the interpreted language is written in.

Answer (score 1):

Original PHP is a very trivial interpreter which does not perform any code generation. But there is an alternative implementation, a PHP to C++ compiler HipHop:

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php